# text is covering the icons in input field reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5I82.png)I have created a multidropdown component. In the input field text is covering the icons as shown below.

I want the text to flow down the icons.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture you have uploaded , If you want the input field text not to overflow over the icons you must specify a width for the input :

```
<input style={{ width : "80%"
// or 200px
 }} />
```

Or If you want the text to go to next line you must use textarea instead of input :

```
<textarea />
```